# Can't add perf probe for C++ methods

Tags: c++, linux, perf

I'm trying to add a `perf probe` for a C++ method in my library, but I keep getting the following:

```
$ perf probe --exec=/path/to/file --add='my::Own::Method'
Semantic error :There is non-digit char in line number.
```

I've listed the available functions like so:

```
$ perf probe --funcs --exec=/path/to/file
```

And tried some C functions that are also included. A probe can be added for these just fine. So I tried the mangled name (e.g. `_ZN2my8Own16Method`) and `perf probe` says it doesn't exist.

Is there a way around this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a workaround you can get the method address with `objdump` and `perf probe` will accept it.

```
  $ perf probe -x /path/file '0x643f30'
Added new event:
  probe_libfile:abs_643f30 (on 0x643f30 in /path/file)

You can now use it in all perf tools, such as:

    perf record -e probe_libfile:abs_643f30 -aR sleep 1
```

Do note that `perf probe` expects an offset from the file, and `objdump` and `readelf` return the address after adjusting for the loading address. For `-pie` executable, where the loading address is 0, the addresses will be the same.
For non `-pie` executables you can get the loading address by looking at the output of `readelf -l /path/file` and searching for the offset `0x000000` and looking at what `VirtAddr` it points to, then subtract that number from the symbol address that you get from `objdump --syms` or `readelf --syms`. It will usually be `0x400000`

Comment: `objdump ./<executable> --syms | grep -i <method>` worked for me. The first column in the output is the address to pass to `perf probe`. But "0x" must be prepended to the address or the perf command will fail.

Answer (score 6):

You can run this to see all the function names in their C++ mangled form:

```
perf probe --exec=/path/to/file --funcs --no-demangle --filter='*'
```

Find the one you want (the actual function name will be amongst the mangled tokens), and add it with the `--no-demangle` option.